Why does the int type change size based on processor architecture while other types do not?
I am studying coding conventions and came across a rule that advises against using the int type. I believe this stems from the characteristic of the int type, which dynamically changes its size based on the processor's bit architecture.
My question is, why are other data types designed to have fixed sizes while the int type is designed to vary depending on the processor's bit architecture? If there are advantages to this approach, why aren't other data types designed to dynamically change their size as well?

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Note that other types may have different sizes as well, e.g., a char may not always necessarily be 8 bits, with this being explained in other posts here such as Will a char always-always-always have 8 bits? and Are there machines, where sizeof(char) != 1, or at least CHAR_BIT > 8?.

What makes you think the other types don't change

@ikegami When I wrote a function that outputs the size of each data type in a general-purpose PC environment, I thought that it was the int data type that changed depending on the number of bits of the processor.

@JohnOmielan thank you! Thanks to this, I learned that what I heard in class only applies in general situations.

btw, the types can even change in size on the same arch. On x86-64, Windows uses a 32-bit long, and Linux uses a 64-bit long.

Other types do change.  In particular, long can be 32 bits or 64 bits — even on systems with 64-bit CPUs.  MS Windows 64-bit has 32-bit long and 64-bit long long, whereas most Unix platforms use 64-bit long and 64-bit long long.  There have been machines (Cray) where sizeof(char) == sizeof(int) (and CHAR_BIT == 32, IIRC).

In fact, the reason I started thinking about these questions was because of MISRA-C. for example, C99 recommends not using the int data type for bit fields, and thinking about this reason led me to worry about the size of the data type. Thanks to you, my curiosity has been somewhat resolved. thank you

If you're concerned with knowing exactly how many bytes data types are, include <stdint.h> and use types like int32_t.

The advice against using int is valid if you need it to be a specific size. The advantage of using int is that it adapts to the processor you run the program on. If you have an 8-bit or a 16-bit processor, you might not want to use a 32-bit value, because that would be way too large for an array index, for example. And expensive to compute.

All of signed char, short, int, long, long long and their unsigned equivalents may change size depending on target (same with floating point types). Each has a minimum required value range that they must support (limits.h), but they can be bigger.
They are that way for historical reasons. Back in the dark ages, people had not figured out the meaning of portability. Some confused ideas floated around like "if I can always use int no matter system then that's portable". And so they let the types vary depending on system. The problem is that when writing truly portable code, you do quite often need to assume an exact value range or byte size of a type. And since you can't do that with int & friends, they because the opposite of portable. It's simply a poorly designed type system inherited from the 1970s and these types should simply be avoided in most professional contexts.
The only types that are designed to have fixed sizes are those in stdint.h like int8_t, int16_t and so on. These are much more portable since you know the size and the signedness format and can adapt the program accordingly.

It is not just int; no single type in C standard has a strict size, except char (sizeof(char) == 1).
Even char might has more than 8 bits.
In C standard it is possible to have a computer with 9-bits or even 16-bits bytes; so we should either have no char available on those machines, or we must have a char type with more than 8 bits.
Other integer types in C standard has these minimum requirements:

short and int: at least 16-bits,
long: at least 32-bits,
long long: at least 64-bits.

C standard has no restriction on integer sizes or even how negative integers are implemented (sign and magnitude, two's complement, ones' complement) which is nice for C language to be more portable.
However C language portability increases programmers' effort to write a C program.
There is also POSIX standard which enforces negative integers to be two's complement and char has exactly 8 bits, short has exactly 16 bits, int has exactly 32 bits.
Similar constraints are also available on 32-bit and 64-bit versions of Microsoft Windows.
So if you are writing a C program to run on a Unix-like OS (Linux distros, BSDs, iOS, macOS, ...) or Microsoft Windows, int has always 32-bits.
In conclusion, C has many implementation defined behaviors, such as int size and range, because it needed to be the most portable programming language.

"which is very good for portability on every machine" Actually it's utter nonsense just there to cause problems, which is why all signed forms but 2's complement are getting removed in the upcoming C23 version of C.

"Also POSIX guaranteed that intN_t and uintN_t (which N is either 8, 16, 32, or 64) are defined in stdint.h" That's guaranteed by ISO C 9899, not by POSIX.

@Lundin if C had fixed char size, it wasn't possible to write a code in C for some hardwares

None of my comments had anything to do with the size of char.

@Lundin ISO C 9899 has no guarantee on availability of intN_t/uintN_t types. They are available only when hardware supports them

@Lundin it is so weird to expect variable size char but expect a fixed size int. So if it is need to have variable size (in bits) char, naturally we ended up in variable size int too

Yeah but if the hardware supports them, then stdint.h must provide them. And all real-world hardwares support them except for oddball DSPs and maybe some low-end 4 or 8 bitters where 64 bit arithmetic becomes ridiculously expensive. But POSIX was never concerned with anything but *nix systems, so...
